# No syntax highlighting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I am coding .cs files in Visual Studio 2013 with an Indie license of Xamarin.
In Xamarin Studio the syntax of following code gets properly highlighted

```
EditText username = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.Username);
EditText pass = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.Password);
```

But in VS it is all in white colors and with no IntelliSense as well.

I could get syntax highlighting working for `.axml` files, but not for Xamarin `.cs` files.

Other `.cs` files, not generated in Xamarin, work fine.

I think this is connected with following using statements

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
```

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 6):

You should remove all files from

```
%User%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

folder.

And restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I know this thread is old now, but I encountered the exact same issue and after a bit of fighting, got it to work again.

I tried all the different suggestions for similar issues (ie. Resetting Visual Studio settings, deleting local AppData, even re-installing both Visual Studio and Xamarin).

What it came down to in my situation was an error in one of my layout files ( `.axml` ) my particular issue was that I had left out my unit for a `layout_height`. Once I fixed it, Cleaned, and did a Build, the highlighting still wasn't working. But with one last restart of Visual Studio I was back up and running.

I was even able to reproduce it a few times to make sure that was a true solution and not some happenstance.

Comment: Me too. When in doubt, restart :P As they say, that's the equivalent of Penicillin in the IT world.

Comment: where are these layout files

Answer (score 1):

The `using` directives here include the `Android` class libraries. Unless the references to these libraries are added to your project, VS does not know what `Android.App` is, for example.

Add the appropriate references to your project.
Once added, the using statements must be correctly recognized and the `EditText` statement must be highlighted too.